# Run-time error '1004' Method 'OnTime' when using MsgBox

Tags: excel, vba, timer

I have a code that works fine until I added a MsgBox confirmation if the user wants to end the timer. The userform just shows a timer starting zero everytime a user starts a task.

I tried replacing *"myTimer", , False* -> *"myTimer", , True* but the timer just continues to increment in the background.

-----Userform-----

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call myTimer
    StartTime = Timer
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, _CloseMode As Integer)
    If MsgBox("Are you sure to End Time?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        myTimer_Cancel
    Else
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

-----Module-----

```
Option Explicit
Public StartTime As Single
Public Sub myTimer()
    Dim elapsedtime As Single
    elapsedtime = Timer - StartTime
    UserForm2.Label2.caption = Format(CDate(elapsedtime / 86400), "hh:nn:ss")
    Application.OnTime Now + timeValue("00:00:01"), "myTimer"
End Sub

Public Sub myTimer_Cancel()
    Application.OnTime Now + timeValue("00:00:01"), "myTimer", , False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you cancel a timer you must use the same exact time you used when you set it, so:

-----Userform-----

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call myTimer
    StartTime = Timer 
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, _CloseMode As Integer)
    If MsgBox("Are you sure to End Time?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        myTimer_Cancel
    Else
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

-----Module-----

```vb
Option Explicit

Public StartTime As Single
Public NextRun ' << store next run time

Public Sub myTimer()
    Dim elapsedtime As Single
    elapsedtime = Timer - StartTime
    UserForm2.Label2.caption = Format(CDate(elapsedtime / 86400), "hh:nn:ss")
    NextRun = Now + timeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime NextRun, "myTimer"
End Sub

Public Sub myTimer_Cancel()
    Application.OnTime NextRun, "myTimer", , False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the valuable lesson and answer Tim. Cheers!